# Sharepoint: process *.asp requests

Tags: sharepoint, asp-classic, url-rewriting, migration, http-status-code-301

we've ported an old ASP site to SharePoint and gone to great lengths to keep the site structure as is with the only change being the change in extension from .asp to .aspx. All .asp requests we 301 redirect to equivalent .aspx page.

Problem is Google does not honour page rank for 301 redirects. This has cause a major problem. So wondering if there is a way to take the request for the .asp page and publish the SharePoint .aspx page but keep the url as is, i.e., no 301 redirect.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SPDoctor. We managed to resolve it pretty simply in the end. In our custom httpmodule, in the context.beginrequest eventhandler, instead of doing a 301 redirect, we simply do a HttpContext.Current.RewritePath to the equivalent .aspx page. It's basically trick 2 in Scott Guthrie's blog post http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

The 301 redirect means "moved permanently" and is the correct way to move pages as far as search engines are concerned. If you do a URL rewrite, which would return the .aspx page to the user agent but at the original .asp URL, the search engine will be no wiser and will continue to keep your old URL in its index.

If you decide to use this approach, you can implement the rewrite using an HTTP module in the ASP.NET pipeline - there is a [URL Rewrite plug-in](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) for IIS which will do this and is easy to configure.

The drawback is that you have to maintain this forever. I would recommend continuing to use a 301 redirect and be patient while Google re-jigs its index. Don't forget the Google web-master tools that can help you with this kind of transition.